# Using CreateDocumentQuery to Azure DocumentDB to pass both field and value to query a collection

Tags: c#-4.0, lambda, azure-cosmosdb

Assume I have a collection, with many documents, and I want to query that collection , where a field has a particular value.  However, I do NOT know ahead of time which field we will be querying.

Here is an example of what I am trying to accomplish:

Document azureDocuments = client.CreateDocumentQuery(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(sDatabaseName, sCollectionCollection)).Where(f => f.MyField=MyValue).AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();

Has anyone done this successfully ?

Answer (score 0):

> Using CreateDocumentQuery to Azure DocumentDB to pass both field and value to query a collection

You could try to dynamically generate a predicate base on the `fieldname` and `fieldvalue` that user provides, and do filter based on the predicate. The following sample code is for your reference.

```
private async Task QueryDocs(string fieldname, string value)
{
    Func<MyDoc, bool> criteria = d => d.id == d.id;

    switch (fieldname)
    {
        case "id":
            criteria = d => d.id == value;
            break;
        case "name":
            criteria = d => d.name == value;
            break;
            //other cases...
    }
    string EndpointUri = "https://mydocumentdbtest.documents.azure.com:443/";
    string PrimaryKey = "{primary key}";
    DocumentClient client;

    client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(EndpointUri), PrimaryKey);

    var query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<MyDoc>(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("{databaseid}", "{collectionid}")).Where(criteria);
    List<MyDoc> list = query.ToList();
}

public class MyDoc
{
    public string id { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is helpful, thank you.  And combined with the fact that , currently, we will only be querying by three, predefined fields, this will work.  Longer term, however, I should like to dynamically query by any field name, not known at compilation time, but at run-time,  as specified by user or application.   Again, thank you, very grateful. -M